# Does the refined Slater's condition hold also in the infinite-dimensional case?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. I have the following optimization problem.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in X}{\text{minimize}} & f(x)\\ \text{subject to} & g_1(x) \leq 0\\ & g_2(x) \leq 0\\ & g_3(x) = 0 \end{array}$$

where functions $f: X \to \mathbb R$ and $g_1: X \to \mathbb R$ are convex and functions $g_2, g_3: X \to \mathbb R$ are affine. I am interested in understanding under which conditions **strong duality** holds for this problem.

I know that if $X$ were finite-dimensional then I could use the "refined" Slater's condition that says that strong duality is attained if there exists an $\overline x \in \mbox{ri}(X)$ such that $g_1(\overline x) < 0$ and $g_2(\overline x) \leq 0$ and $g_3(\overline x) = 0$. In other words, strict feasibility for the convex constraint and standard feasibility for the affine constraint and of course for the equality constraint.

Does something similar exist when $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, e.g., $L_p$?

Comment: I don't know off-hand, but the last chapter of the wonderful "Convex Analysis and Nonlinear Optimization" by Borwein and Lewis deals with the infinite-dimensional case and the various pathologies that occur there (as well as the results that carry over from the fin-dim case).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anything on this matter there.

Comment: @Abumze978 Would Theorem 1 on page 224 of the book "Optimization by vector space methods" by Luenberger solve your problem?